# How not to add a directory with files to final apk

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I would like to not add my directory with files .txt, .json etc. to final .apk.
But I need this files during build apk. <- currently I have done this

Does gradle has that possibility ?

Comment: Which directory?

Comment: my custom directory, I added this manually and now I see this file in apk

Comment: for example directory in assets